# ProFTPD pub key authentication, still asks for password

Tags: ftp, sftp, proftpd

I've set up mod_sftp with ProFTPD, and for some reason it still prompts me for a password when I connect.

This is my `conf.d/myserver` file:

```
SFTPEngine on
SFTPLog /var/log/sftp.log
Port 7770
SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys file:/etc/proftpd/authorized_keys/%u
SFTPCompression delayed
MaxLoginAttempts 6
DefaultRoot ~
Umask 002
CreateHome on 770 dirmode 770
```

And the public key for the user is in `/etc/proftpd/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Make sure the user ProFTPD is running as can access the public key file(s).

Comment: Yep, no problem there.

Comment: Can try adding `SFTPAuthMethods publickey` (will block using passwords) but the default should already be `publickey password` - perhaps the client doesn't have the private key or is set to always try to use a password?

Comment: can you check/report the permissions on the users authorized_keys file in `/etc/proftpd/authorized_keys/%u` as well as ownership?

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this, and it was caused by what looks like a bug in `ssh-keygen` that manifests when you convert the ssh-rsa format key into the RFC-4716 key format: the **Comment** header is too long.

To confirm that this is happening to you, enable the SFTPLog option in your `proftpd.conf` file, then in the SFTP log file you'll see lines like the following, specifically the "line too long" part:

```
Jul 25 19:11:25 mod_sftp/0.9.7[16355]: public key fingerprint: 77:fa:c7:d6:da:b9:99:6f:9d:5f:74:30:ba:09:4f:e9
Jul 25 19:11:25 mod_sftp/0.9.7[16355]: line too long (74) on line 1 of '/etc/proftpd.d/authorized_keys/myusername'
Jul 25 19:11:25 mod_sftp/0.9.7[16355]: Make sure that '/etc/proftpd.d/authorized_keys/myusername' is a RFC4716 formatted key
Jul 25 19:11:25 mod_sftp/0.9.7[16355]: error base64-decoding key data in '/etc/proftpd.d/authorized_keys/myusername'
Jul 25 19:11:25 mod_sftp/0.9.7[16355]: error comparing keys from '/etc/proftpd.d/authorized_keys/myusername': Invalid argument
Jul 25 19:11:25 mod_sftp/0.9.7[16355]: sending userauth failure; remaining userauth methods: publickey,password
Jul 25 19:11:29 mod_sftp/0.9.7[16355]: disconnecting client (received EOF)
```

Take a look at the offending key, and you'll see how it sticks out:
[image: Excess line text]

Trim that off with your text editor of choice, and key auth should start working. Using bash it looks like this, where user.pub is your key file:

```
cut -c 1-72 user.pub | sed '/^Comment: "[^"]*$/ s/$/"/' > user.pub
```

If you instead want to keep the whole comment, you'll need to escape the end of the line and put it on the next one. See the [example section of RFC 4716](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4716#section-3.6) for how you can re-format comments.

Finally, I ran into this problem using `ssh-keygen` on CentOS 6.9. The version I have on Mac OS Sierra truncates the key comments properly to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The current value of SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys is set to use per-user files of authorized keys.  I would guess that for a given user, let's use jsmith as an example, their key would need to go into a file called /etc/proftpd/authorized_keys/jsmith.

To get your current setup working try changing the value of SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys to /etc/proftpd/authorized_keys.

See http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html#SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys for more detail.